# Why are deleted contacts showing in search results?

Tags: search, delete

I just upgraded a Drupal site to `5.27.1` and am noticing that when I do a search for contacts, contacts that are in the trash are also showing up in results (which did not happen before). I was able to reproduce this on the official demo server as well (reporting `5.29.alpha1`) by deleting a contact and then running a search with that deleted contact's name -- they still show up in the results.

When I click on the contact record it still does show correctly that the contact is deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is already [reported on git lab](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1864) and has fixed at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17798

The fix is available in 5.27.2 version of Civi. Try upgrading Civi to 5.27.2

Answer (score 1):

Ah, found this: [Advanced Search returns contacts in Trash even if 'Search in Trash' not ticked](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1864) which links to this pull:

- https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17798